# Running spark job not shown in the UI

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-1.6

I have submitted my spark job as mentioned here `bin/spark-submit --class DataSet BasicSparkJob-assembly-1.0.jar` without mentioning the `--master` parameter or `spark.master` parameter. Instead of that job gets submitted to my 3 node spark cluster. But i was wondering where it submitted the job because it is not showing any information in the `Running Applications`

Comment: If you have set "conf.setMaster("local[X]")" inside your application, it will always run locally even if you submit it to "--master  URL"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not set the master in `--master` nor `spark.master` Spark will run locally.

You could still view the progress of your job. By default the UI will be availalbe during the running of your spark job on `http://localhost:4040`.

When your job finishes, this UI will be killed and you could not view the history of your application unless you configured Spark history server

Comment: Does it use the same configuration mentioned in the spark-default.conf for the memory and core for processing?

Comment: if you mean the spar history server,  it uses `spark-defaults.conf`as its configuration file, but the history server itself is not a Spark process, meaning that it is not started as Spark with driver/executors

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that Spark is running your in local mode on your development machine.

Comment: Ok, Is there a way where i can see the logs of the this running application then?

Comment: You can access the Web-UI using `localhost:4040`.